# Apply remote validation for hidden field in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, remote-validation

The remote validation for the hidden field in mvc does not get fired 
**Model :**

```
[Remote("checker", "mycontroller", ErrorMessage = "Valid combination of phone and account number required.", HttpMethod = "Get")]
        public string Validate_cart { get; set; }
```

**View :**

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Validate_Paris)
```

**Also tried setting value by using jquery :**

```
$("#Phone_Number").blur(function () {
$("#Validate_cart").val = "dummy"
});
```

using jquery or by model the value is set but validations do not get fired. I checked using fiddler there is no call for the method being made anytime.

**Method**

```
 [HttpGet]
        public  bool checker(string Validate_cart )
        {
            try
            {

                bool isValid = //code to hit database to check the record
                return !isValid;               

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hidden fields are ignored by jquery validation by default. this is due to the following setting.

```
$("form").validate().settings.ignore
```

this is set to ":hidden" so that validation ignores all hidden fields. What you can do is change the selector assigned in for ignore as follows.

```
$(function(){
    $("form").validate().settings.ignore = ":hidden:not([id*=Validate_cart])";
});
```

Then it should fire the remote validation

Comment: still it does not fire the validation.

Comment: Can you please update your post with the `checker` `action` code